# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when running activator command in IDEA terminal

Tags: java, scala, playframework, sbt, typesafe-activator

So this was all going well with my old computer but when I try to pack up my project on my new computer environment using "activator dist" or any other activator command in IDEA terminal, it shows:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: activator/package$RichIO$
        at activator.RepositoryConfig$.replaceSection(RepositoryConfig.scala:239)
        at activator.RepositoryConfig$.configureUserRepositories(RepositoryConfig.scala:91)
        at activator.RepositoryConfig$.configureUserRepositories(RepositoryConfig.scala:84)
        at activator.ActivatorLauncher.run(ActivatorLauncher.scala:32)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:128)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:35)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:18)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:41)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:17)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: activator.package$RichIO$
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 13 more
Error during sbt execution: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: activator/package$RichIO$
```

my sbt.version is 0.13.5 activator version is 1.3.12 and here is part of my build.sbt

```
name := "react-play"

version := "1.0"

lazy val `react-play` = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.12.4"
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Okay so it seems that I solved my problem by updating my **sbt.version** from **0.13.5** to **0.13.17** and changing my jdk version to **1.8.0_201**. 
Not sure which one did the trick though.